# Splunk event increasing logic witch each SPL query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I am getting data in Splunk from Snowflake using Splunk DB Connect. This is just simple orders data. At Splunk search & reporting I am running the following query on my table to get visualization.

```
source="big_data_table_inner_join" "UNITS_SOLD" | top COUNTRY
```

What I am seeing is that each time I run query the events number at splunk increases quite heavily. For eg. After running first time they were **342000** events and when I ran the same query they were **67445** events. Any idea why is this happening?